# Why use bracket notation in this case is working?

Tags: javascript

I'm studying Javascript and I came across this challenge(Must return how many pairs of socks is in the pile) in Hackerrank that I could not resolve, so I search for the answer and I found this one but I can not understand why it is working, like, why using bracket notation with the object socks is returning some numbers and some undefined? Socks is supposed to be empty.

```
function sockMerchant(n, arr) {
    // var sorted = arr.sort();

    let socks = {}
    let pairs = 0;
    for (let i=0; i < n; i++) {
        // console.log(socks[arr[i]])


        socks[arr[i]] = socks[arr[i]] + 1 || 1;


        if (socks[arr[i]] % 2 === 0) {
            pairs += 1
        }
    }
    return console.log(pairs)
}

sockMerchant(11, [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20, 50, 50])
```

Comment: Because all it does is count distinct values by treating the values in the input array as _keys_ in a counting object. It's literally as if you took some paper, and wrote down tallies for each "sock number" as you ran through the array yourself. You see "10", so 10 gets 1 tally. You see 20, so 20 gets a tally. You see 20 again, you give 20 another tally, now it has two tallies. And every time you add an even tally, you know you have a pair of socks.

Comment: This part: `return console.log(pairs)` is not correct, because it will always return `undefined`, so it should be changed to: `return pairs;`. Also when we call a function, we need to store the result, so change this: `sockMerchant(11, [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20, 50, 50])` into this: `let pairs = sockMerchant(11, [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20, 50, 50]); console.log(pairs);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break down this code:

we are calling `sockMerchant(11, [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20, 50, 50])`

- n is the number or steps
- arr is the array

Cool.

we set default values

```js
let socks = {} //<- socks mapping object [sock_name, count]
let pairs = 0;
```

Now we loop from 0 to n and do the following:

- up the count of socks found for that socks

```js
socks[arr[i]] = socks[arr[i]] + 1 || 1;
```

- if the number is even -> bump pairs number

lets do some iterations:

- socks[10] = 1
  pairs = 0
- socks[20] = 1
  pairs = 0
- socks[20] = 1+1 == 2
  pairs = 1
- socks[10] = 1+1 == 2
  pairs = 2
- socks[10] = 2+1 == 3
  pairs = 2
  ...

Using bracket notation on an object/map can both react the value, or set/create one

Last but not least:
console.log always returns undefined.
Use `return pairs`

```js
function sockMerchant(n, arr) {
    // init
    let socks = {}
    let pairs = 0;
    for (let i=0; i < n; i++) {
        // bump sock 'arr[i]' count
        socks[arr[i]] = socks[arr[i]] + 1 || 1;

        // check if has a pair
        if (socks[arr[i]] % 2 === 0) {
            pairs += 1
        }
    }

    return pairs
}

foundPairs = sockMerchant(11, [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20, 50, 50])

// foundPairs = 4
```

[image: socks iterations]